# Recover Windows to Go (BitLocker enabled)

Tags: data-recovery, bitlocker, windows-to-go

How can I recover (maybe just use start up repair??) Windows to Go on USB?

When I want to boot the PC it asks for the BitLocker password. I type it and it starts to boot. Then it crashes with an error 0x000...01 (... means lots of 0).

If I put this USB stick into a normal Windows 8.1, it's not mounting, but in Disk Management shows that there is a volume with no drive letter, and in the file system tab shows *Unknown (BitLocker Encrypted)*.

The USB stick is a Kingston DataTraveler WorkSpace 32GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by this article: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/21714-bitlocker-repair-tool-recover-drive-windows-7-8-a.html

This recover data, so I can reinstall Windows To Go into my USB stick.